# Why the ⟨code⟩ of \NewDocumentCommand{⟨cmd⟩}{⟨arg spec⟩}{⟨code⟩} isn't displayed in the terminal?

Tags: macros, expl3, terminal-output

Consider the following MCE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mynewcommand}{foo}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyNewDocumentCommand}{}{bar}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\iow_term:x {mynewcommand=\mynewcommand}
\iow_term:x {MyNewDocumentCommand=\MyNewDocumentCommand}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \verb|\mynewcommand|=\mynewcommand
\item \verb|\MyNewDocumentCommand|=\MyNewDocumentCommand
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

When it is compiled, what it is displayed:

- in the resulting PDF is expected:

  ```
    • \mynewcommand=foo
    • \MyNewDocumentCommand=bar
  ```
- in the terminal is expected for `\mynewcommand` but is unexpected for `\MyNewDocumentCommand`:

  ```
    mynewcommand=foo
    MyNewDocumentCommand=\MyNewDocumentCommand
  ```

Why, in the terminal, the `⟨code⟩` of `\NewDocumentCommand{⟨cmd⟩}{⟨arg spec⟩}{⟨code⟩}` isn't displayed, whereas the `⟨code⟩` of `\newcommand{⟨cmd⟩}[⟨num⟩][⟨default⟩]{⟨code⟩}` is displayed?

Comment: commands defined with \NewDocumentCommand are protected (robust).

Comment: try  `\newcommand{\mynewcommand}[1][]{foo}` you will see why `\protected` is used here

Comment: @UlrikeFischer OK, thanks. Is it possible to force this `⟨code⟩` to be displayed?

Comment: use `\ShowCommand`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK (with `\ShowCommand` not inside `\iow_term:x`).

Comment: In the shown example you could use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`. But in other cases, this isn't a good idea. So it depends on what you do and want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `\newcommand\macro` then the `\macro` is defined using TeX primitives `\long\def\macro`. The macro is expanded inside `\edef` and inside `\write` and `\message` primitives, i.e. when you write an information into the terminal or log file.

On the other hand, if you use `\NewDocumentCommand\macro` then the macro is defined by TeX primitives `\protected\def\macro` (and the macro body is more complicated in this case). When the `\macro` is defined as `\protected` then it is expanded in typesetting context but it isn't expanded in `\edef`, `\write`, `\message`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd expect that output. For instance

```
\iow_term:x { LaTeX=\LaTeX }
```

will stop with a weird error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\S@10 ->\gdef \tf@size
                       {10}\gdef \sf@size {7}\gdef \ssf@size {5}
```

If you want to use `\NewDocumentCommand` to define a container for some text (but you shouldn't), then do

```
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\MyNewDocumentCommand}{}{bar}
```

and now

```
\iow_term:x {MyNewDocumentCommand=\MyNewDocumentCommand}
```

will indeed produce

```
MyNewDocumentCommand=bar
```

I'm not sure what would this be useful for.

Comment: Why do you recommend to not use the `\NewDocumentCommand` to define a container for a text ?

Comment: Are you advising `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` instead of `\NewDocumentCommand` to define a container for a text?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I'm advising `\newcommand`