# \graphicspath{{⟨cmd⟩/}}: graphic files found if ⟨cmd⟩ defined with \newcommand but not found with \DeclareDocumentCommand

Tags: macros, graphics, expl3, protected-macro

Suppose a graphic file `myimage` contained in a subdirectory `images` of the current directory.

With the following MCE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\ImagesDirectory}{images}

\graphicspath{{\ImagesDirectory/}}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{myimage}
\end{document}
```

the graphic file `myimage` is found.

But, with  the following MCE where `\newcommand{\ImagesDirectory}{...}` is replaced by `\DeclareDocumentCommand{\ImagesDirectory}{}{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\ImagesDirectory}{}{images}

\graphicspath{{\ImagesDirectory/}}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{myimage}
\end{document}
```

the graphic file `myimage` is not found.

Why and is there a workaround still relying on `\DeclareDocumentCommand` or friends (and not `\newcommand` and friends)?

Comment: [Same expansion problem as before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685201/why-the-code-of-newdocumentcommand-cmd-arg-spec-code-isnt-displayed). Try `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`.

Comment: `DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand `

Comment: @cabohah Sigh... I've seen your comment a few seconds too late.

Comment: Why this expandability is involved in the context of `\graphicpath`?

Comment: how should latex get at the content if you hide it behind a protection wall?

Comment: Usually I think it as "`\graphicpath` is only guaranteed to work if you pass explicit path and does not contain special character etc. If it also works with defined commands it's implementation side effect, but that only work when commands are expandable." -- in the process of "simplifying" LaTeX for the users, expandability things like that are not very well-documented (actually I didn't check the LaTeX book) which imply several things count as "works by implementation".